Configuring apache as reverse proxy for varnish server without using Hitch on ubuntu 22.04
I am trying to configure varnish cache 7 with apache2 on my server. Though setting up http request works just fine. but varnish can't handle https directly so i tried Apache and Hitch but didn't worked form. Now if any one can help me find a working configuration for varnish and Apache only.
my other question here is do i have to use two virtual hosts?
enter image description here
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Apache HTTP Host 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName mycloud.com
    #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mycloud.com

    <Directory var/www/mycloud.com>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
    </Directory>
    
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined    
    

</VirtualHost>


++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Apache HTTPS Host 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName mycloud.com
    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mycloud.com
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycloud.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycloud.com/privkey.pem
    
    # Set up proxy headers
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyAddHeaders On
    
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
   
     # Add headers to prevent redirect loops
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
   
    # Optional: Log forwarding headers for debugging
    LogLevel debug
    Header add X-Forwarded-Proto "https" env=HTTPS
    Header add X-Forwarded-Port "443" env=HTTPS
    
    ProxyPass /test http://127.0.0.1:80
    ProxyPassReverse /test http://127.0.0.1:80
      

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>


++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Varnish VLC
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto ~ "https") {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.X-Varnish = bereq.http.X-Varnish;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
        set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
}

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Varnish Service 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

[Unit]
Description=Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
Documentation=https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/ man:varnishd

[Service]
Type=simple

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
LimitNOFILE=131072

# Locked shared memory - should suffice to lock the shared memory log
# (varnishd -l argument)
# Default log size is 80MB vsl + 1M vsm + header -> 82MB
# unit is bytes
LimitMEMLOCK=85983232
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd \
          -j unix,user=vcache \
          -F \
          -a :80 \
          -a localhost:6092,PROXY \
          -p feature=+http2 \
          -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
          -s malloc,256m

ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/varnishreload
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateDevices=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


i tried with Hitch for TLS termination but the configuration is too complex for me. so it didn't work out.

You can use Apache as a reverse proxy TLS terminator, but it'll perform better if you use Apache Traffic Server. Apache Traffic Server can also cache objects as well.

While I can't really help you with the Apache TLS proxy part, I can help you with installing & configuring Hitch.
If you need Varnish because you get too many requests on your Apache web server, it is best to avoid Apache to handle TLS termination too.
Let's start with a quick install guide, which is based on our official tutorial.
Installing Hitch on Debian or Ubuntu
If you're planning to run Varnish & Hitch on a Debian or Ubuntu system, please run the following commands to prepare the install:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install debian-archive-keyring curl gnupg apt-transport-https
curl -s -L https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/hitch/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -

Then run the following command to connect to our custom package repository:
. /etc/os-release
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hitch.list > /dev/null <<-EOF
deb https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/hitch/$ID/ $VERSION_CODENAME main
EOF
sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/hitch > /dev/null <<-EOF
Package: hitch
Pin: release o=packagecloud.io/varnishcache/*
Pin-Priority: 1000
EOF


After that it's just a matter of updating & installing:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hitch

Installing Hitch on Red Hat or Centos systems
If you're using a Red Hat or Centos variant to install Hitch, just run the following command to prepare the install:
. /etc/os-release
sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/hitch.repo > /dev/null <<-EOF
[varnishcache_hitch]
name=varnishcache_hitch
baseurl=https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/hitch/el/${VERSION_ID%%.*}/$(arch)
repo_gpgcheck=0
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/hitch/gpgkey
sslverify=1
sslcacert=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
metadata_expire=300
EOF

And then it's simply a matter of running sudo yum install hitch  to install Hitch.
Configuring Hitch
The proxy & TLS configuration for Hitch is located in /etc/hitch/hitch.conf.
Here's an example config:
frontend = "[*]:443"
daemon = on
user = "hitch"
group = "hitch"
backend = "[localhost]:6092"
pem-dir = "/etc/hitch/cert.d"
pem-dir-glob = "*.pem"
pem-file = "/etc/hitch/cert.pem"
alpn-protos = "h2, http/1.1"
write-proxy-v2 = on

I noticed in your systemd configuration for Varnish that port 6092 is configured as a listening port for PROXY traffic. That's ideal: I referenced 6092 in the backend configuration and I enabled PROXY traffic to Varnish through the write-proxy-v2 = on setting.
The fact that you have HTTP/2 support enabled through the -p feature=+http2 runtime parameter, allows use to set alpn-protos = "h2, http/1.1" in Hitch to enforce HTTP/2 traffic.
What about the certificates?
As specified in the hitch.conf file, certificates are stored in the /etc/hitch/cert.d folder. Please your .pem files in that folder.
The certificates must have the .pem extension for them to be picked up by Hitch. This was configured through the pem-dir-glob = "*.pem" setting. You're free to change that.
If you want to load certificates from another folder, just update the pem-dir = "/etc/hitch/cert.d" setting.
Don't forget to run sudo systemctl restart hitch when you change settings.
Detecting HTTPS traffic in Varnish
Hitch is a pure TLS proxy with no real HTTP/HTTPS awareness. The X-Forwarded-Proto can be used to create that awareness and to communicate that to the backend services.
Unlike your Apache example, we cannot set the X-Forwarded-Proto header in the TLS proxy, because Hitch (as mentioned) doesn't have that HTTP awareness.
However, we can use information from the PROXY protocol to determine whether or not the connection was done over TLS.
Here's a very simple snippet of VCL that you can include in your own VCL configuration:
vcl 4.1;

import proxy;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if(!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        if (proxy.is_ssl()) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "http";
        }
    }    
}

sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
}

As you can see, the proxy.is_ssl() function is used to fetch potential TLS information from the PROXY connection. If the function returns true, we know it was an HTTPS request and we set the X-Forwarded-Proto header accordingly.
That header will also be used by your application to create the right URL schemes for hyperlinks. And because we add the value of that header to our caching hash, Varnish will store HTTP & HTTPS variants of an object separately.

thank you for your feedback. I am go to check report back.
